# NestJS Annotation with dynamically params

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Is it possible to add params dynamically in one annotation on NestJS?

Like this:

```js
const myParam = config.service.param;

@Annotation(myParam)
public myMethod() {

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Technically, the answer is yes, but only if the value passed to the decorator is already resolved at the time of importing the file containing the decorator. In other words, you can't use class members (like Nest's `ConfigService`) because decorators run against the file as soon as the file is imported, but you could use something like `process.env` if you use `dotenv` and read the config first thing, before you import any other files